# I am using XNA to do rotation of an image. I want it to rotate in one direction then back so it kinda does a back and forth motion

Tags: c#, image, xna

I am using XNA to do rotation of an image.  I want it to rotate in one direction then back so it kinda does a back and forth motion.

however for some reason my code isnt working.  It rotates left then stops.
So if anyone can tell me why?  Also its in C# in case someone was wondering.

```
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
bool goleft = true;
//Calculate rotation angle based on time elapsed
float circle = MathHelper.Pi * 2;
elapsed *= 2;

if (RotationAngle >= 0.7f)
{
goleft = true;
}

if (RotationAngle <= -0.7f)
{
goleft = false;
}

switch (goleft)
{
     case true:
                RotationAngle -= elapsed % circle;
                break;

     case false:
                RotationAngle += elapsed % circle;
                break;
}
```

EDIT: Added a little more code to top for variables.  Sorry about that.

Also without the switch statement and just having 1 RotationAngle += etc.  It works and goes around in a complete circle. However I want it to go back and forth instead of around.

Comment: Pi * 2.  But Ill add it to the top.

Comment: What is your condition to initiate the rotation? Because from what I see once you rotate in either direction you will never meet the condition required to rotate in the opposite direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `bool goleft = true;` added in the Update? Because it will reset to true everytime then I believe. Been a while since I used XNA!

Comment: OMG i did not even notice.  I looked at it for about an hour now.  Thank you so much....it is always the small things

Comment: No problem! And indeed it is always in the small things haha!